# Creating new std::string in x64 C++ dll that is called by C# via pinvoke

Tags: c#, c++, dll, interop

I am trying to build a C++ dll out of a complex existing C++ project that is being built for x64.

I am current just exporting a single very simple function as a test.

```
extern "C"{
    void suthPsEval(const char *a, const char *b, char *result, int len)
    {

        int aLen = 0;
        for (int i = 0; a[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            result[i] = a[i];
            aLen++;
        }
        for (int j = 0; b[j] != '\0'; j++){
            result[aLen + j] = b[j];
        }
        //std::vector<std::string> foo;  //THIS LINE CRASHES PROGRAM???
    }
}
```

When I comment out the line that tries to create a vector of strings things work as I expect, I am able to call the exported function from my C# and it correctly concatenates strings.  Similarly when I run the full code (after uncommenting the line in question) in a different test Win32 DLL that I built everything works properly.

However in the x64 DLL the single line that declares foo causes the program to crash with a System.AccessViolationException.

I assume there is some simple explanation for this and hopefully an easy way to work around it.  I am very new to C++ so I have no idea how to solve this problem.  The complex C++ code that I need to interface with is highly dependent on being about to create strings and vectors.

Is it possible to convert the x64 dll to Win32 or is that likely to break everything?

Comment: It's exactly that one line that you're adding/removing?  You're not trying to hand the vector over to C# or any wackiness like that?

Comment: Does it still fail spectacularly if you move the `std::vector` out to a C++ function that's _not_ wrapped by `extern "C"`, and call that function from this one?

Comment: @cHao it is exactly that one line, I'm not doing anything with the vector.

Comment: @JoeZ I get the same behavior if I make a function void temp() outside the extern "C" and move the crashing line into temp and call it.  When the line is commented out things work, when uncommented it crashes.

Comment: My knowledge of Windows DLL programming is limited.  Based on the experiment you just tried (moving the `vector` line out of `extern "C"`), it feels like a C++ environment initialization step is missing, but that's just with my vague understanding of how runtime environments work, not anything specific to Win32 or Win64.